# Android Widget shows strange image during update

Tags: android, widget, motorola

I have a strange one here...
I have a Motorola i1 with Nextel running android 1.5

I have an android widget. 
When I start running the Service that updates this Widget I see an image from another widget (Launch DC Contact)

It shows this image in my widget's location but when "update" of my widget is done it is replaced with the layout I have for my widget.

It is as if there is a cache of widget images and it shows stuff from there until my widget's update is done.

If my update takes long then user can see this strange image for 2-3 secs.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Enter onUpdate");
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_initial_layout);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.WidgetLayout, pendingIntent);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.NEWCountTextView, Integer.toString(NEWC));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.ACKCountTextView, Integer.toString(ACKC));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.PKUCountTextView, Integer.toString(PKUC));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.PODCountTextView, Integer.toString(PODC));
            if (errorMessage.contentEquals("")) {
                errorMessage = (new Date()).toString();
                views.setTextColor(R.id.LastUpdatedTextView, Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                views.setTextColor(R.id.LastUpdatedTextView, Color.RED);
            }
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.LastUpdatedTextView, errorMessage);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Exit onUpdate");
    }

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Enter onReceive");
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.contentEquals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE")) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            NEWC = extras.getInt("NEWCOUNT");
            ACKC = extras.getInt("ACKCOUNT");
            PKUC = extras.getInt("PKUCOUNT");
            PODC = extras.getInt("PODCOUNT");
            errorMessage = extras.getString("ERRORMESSAGE");
        }
    }
```

super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Exit onReceive");
}
here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/WidgetLayout" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:text="ORDERS" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="6dip"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"        
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/CountsLinearLayout" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView 
                android:text="NEW" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView11" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />
            <TextView 
                android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/NEWCountTextView" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView 
                android:text="ACK" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView21" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />
            <TextView 
                android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/ACKCountTextView" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView 
                android:text="PKU" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView31" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView 
                android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/PKUCountTextView" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout06" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView 
                android:text="POD" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView41" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView 
                android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/PODCountTextView" 
                android:layout_width="75dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
        android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="6dip"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/LastUpdatedTextView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />                  
</LinearLayout>
```

Have you seen anything like this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue in my widget as you described and searched a lot for a solution and couldn't find any. What I ended up doing is some kind of workaround that seems to work fine in my case. What i did is the following, instead of updating the widgets directly from the onUpdate() method, I started a service that handled the update then killed itself. This solved it on the emulator and on a device that had the widget stuck during update.
Here's a sample code:

The AppWidgetProvider:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));
}
```

The Service:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    started(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    started(intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}


private void started(Intent intent) {
    //update here the widgets
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    updateWidgets(context);
    stopSelf();//killing the service
}

private void updateWidgets(Context context) {
    AppWidgetManager appmanager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName cmpName = new ComponentName(context, widgetClass);
    int[] widgetIds = appmanager.getAppWidgetIds(cmpName);
    RemoteViews rView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutId);
    for (int wid : widgetIds) {
        //all updates here
        rView.setTextViewText(tvId, desc);
        appmanager.updateAppWidget(wid, rView);
    }
}
```

Note sure why this workaround solves the issue, but the good thing is that it does
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on 4.0 & 4.2 when manually sending `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast to update the widget.
Fixed by using a custom action, e.g.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
    <action android:name="my.app.action.APPWIDGET_REFRESH" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: please I am in the same situation, please what kind of custom action did you use???